# How to analyze an HTML text with compound words

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, nest, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm writing a search service based on Elasticsearch for a bunch of sites with content written in agglutinated languages like Swedish, German and Finnish.

I know that Elasticsearch offers language analyzers by default but after some testing I found their support sloppy at best.

What I got so far is:

```
{
  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "filter":{
        "swedish_stop":{
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_swedish_"
        },
        "swedish_stemmer":{
          "type":"stemmer",
          "language":"swedish"
        },
        "swedish_words":{
          "type":"dictionary_decompounder",
          "word_list":["very", "long", "list", "of", "words", "almost", "13", "MB"]
        }
      },
      "analyzer":{
        "custom_swedish":{
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":[
            "lowercase",
            "swedish_stop",
            "swedish_stemmer",
            "swedish_words"
          ],
          "char_filter":[
            "html_strip"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do you guys have a clue?

Comment: what is the specific question?

Comment: "given an HTML text written in a nordic language, what's the best way to analyze it so that compound words are properly decomposed and indexed?"